# Using node.js in a fleet management application

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

I have a gps fleet management application that I think would greatly benefit from using node.js. I just started to look into node.js and still think I have much to learn, but would appreciate your advice and direction.

To give you and idea of our current setup:

> A java app receives, compiles, and parses gps records into mySql db.
>   The users than, though our application, query the database every 6 sec for the last record for a particular gps unit. During the day there are about 9 million records that are inserted into the database.

So would I would like to do is to use and include node.js within our java app and utilize it to send gps data to the client browser without it being queried into the database. In other words, i was thinking to do a small function that checks gps id (about 5000 ids in total) and compare to client id (200 in total) and based on that send that to the required node.js channel.

Providing that I do not have much experience with node.js, I would greatly appreciate it if you can tell me if my logic is sound and that node.js is the right way to go?

Thanks,

Comment: Why is your application querying the db every 6 seconds? Is that necessary? I think the technology you are eluding to is a socket connection, which is not specific to node at all, and can be done with many languages including java. node also has nothing to do with java, but is a library for server side javascript. java is in no way related to javascript.

Comment: @dqhendricks Thanks for comment. We query it every 6 seconds because we want to provide our clients with current vehicle status as fast as possible, because most of our clients purchase our system because of this feature. So our thinking was that if it would be possible to push the data to the browser as the information became available, instead of just the client browser doing a recurring query every 6 seconds. This solution has worked fine, but as the number of trackers increases our system is becoming incredibly slow.

Comment: Well then, you are on the right track with socket.io for the client side of your web application, but node may not make sense to be using if the rest of your server side application is written in Java. You could write the socket server on the server side using Java just as well. The real advantage to using node.js is that it is event driven with non-blocking network calls (MySQL). This means it doesn't have to create a new thread each time a connection is made, exhausting your systems memory very quickly, and it doesn't have to stop everything it is doing when waiting for a response from mysql

Comment: Well on our server side only the GPS-tracker socket listener and database parser is in Java. The rest of the application is written in php and javascript. At any rate, what I am aiming to achieve is (provided that is doable) to send to the client browser the gps data as soon as it comes into the java listener without it being sent through the db. Continues on the next comment[...]

Comment: Continued from the comment above 
For example: 
>GPS units makes a TCP/IP connection to the java socket application and starts sending gps logs
>Java socket app, decompiles and at the same time,
  -parses the data into db,
  -filters gps data (that is specific to a client) and pushes it to the browser via node.js (socket.io)
This, I think that it would eliminate our recurring 6 sec requests to the database. I hope this makes thing clearer.

Comment: but why would you need node? You can have socket.io connect directly to the java socket server with no need for node.

Comment: Sorry for bringing this old question. I have similar situations as you describe, If you get solution then can you post it?

Comment: @AhmadSuhendri, We can't get a solution on this situation. Because Node.js is not multi-thread and also maybe it is not so fit for this situation. Nodejs is perfect (because I use it) of real time notification, chat and these thing, but maybe not for our situation. So the didn't do something on this way. Sorry that I didn't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

if you are already using Java why not using something like CometD (http://cometd.org/) it has the same (or similar) push functionality to Socket.io and it is already Java based. If you are using a java container other than Jetty, Atmosphere (https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) is another good option with lots of container support.

Generally speaking I think your designed is a bit flawed for "real time". When you get the updates you should be directly pushing them to the customer if they are connected and have an active "subscription" for the info. You can still update the database but why is the database the central clearing house for this information in a "push" model? It would make more sense to push directly to some kind of websocket style solution while you update the database in parallel. Then the only people querying the database are users logging in for a new session to get the "last historical point" and all subsequent updates are pushed without the the need for any database queries.

Anyone have any thoughts?